# Unable to get the source file of an error on react-native

Tags: react-native, debugging, hook

I am debugging an application that throws me the error of

```
     ERROR    Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a 
function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    [Fri Oct 23 2020 09:04:14.325]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

But it doesn't say where is the source file of the error... since it is a big application I am having trouble finding where this error is located.

I am able to compile the application but the error happens on the initialization.
When I run the debugger it says the following on the developers console...

> Unable to symbolicate stack trace: The stack is null

Plus the previous errors.
Any idea how I could locate the source file of this errors?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Most likely related to a `useEffect` or `useState` hook call. Perhaps you have one in your render?

Comment: I haven't used _useEffect_ or _useState_ in any part of the app :/

Comment: do you happen to be using a hook in your `return` function?